# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-bootstrap' issue

Tags: reactjs

I am getting Module not found: Can't resolve `react-bootstrap` error while importing component FormControl.

```
import { ControlLabel, 
        FormControl,
        HelpBlock,
        Form,
        Col,
        FormGroup,
        Checkbox } from 'react-bootstrap'
```

Comment: Did you tried `npm -i react-bootstrap --save`

Answer (score 1):

You do not have this package installed. So, like Harish Soni said, running the following command

```sh
npm i react-bootstrap --save
```

alternatively if using yarn:

```
yarn add react-bootstrap
```

This will solve the issue.

Comment: Would you please remove dash before i in nmp i? this is not working like that